# Can I make a WAR depend on a JNDI entry in JBoss 5.1?

Tags: deployment, jndi, war, jboss5.x, ear

As part of an upgrade from JBoss 4.0.4 to 5.1, I am trying to get a WAR to deploy after an EAR is successfully deployed.  JBoss 5.x does not support [PrefixDeploymentSorter](http://community.jboss.org/message/201628#201628) like 4.x did, which means that I have to use <depends> in the WAR's jboss-web.xml.

It seems I [cannot depend on the EAR](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-3654?focusedCommentId=12343310#action_12343310) itself, so I pick the last deployed EJB instead.  This EJB provides a JNDI entry that the WAR needs.

Here's the EJB as it deploys when the WAR is absent from the deploy directory:

```
2010-03-25 10:47:30,348 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer] (main) Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=my-ear.ear,jar=mypackage-ejb.jar,name=MyFacadeBean,service=EJB3
2010-03-25 10:47:30,350 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer] (main) STARTED EJB: my.package.MyFacadeBean ejbName: MyFacadeBean
2010-03-25 10:47:30,371 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.jndiregistrar.JndiSessionRegistrarBase] (main) Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

        my/MyFacade/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
        my-ear/MyFacadeBean/local-my.package.MyFacade - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

And here's the depends snippet from jboss-web.xml:

```
<depends>jboss.j2ee:ear=my-ear.ear,jar=mypackage-ejb.jar,name=MyFacadeBean,service=EJB3</depends>
```

My problem is:  The WAR starts to deploy immediately after "STARTED EJB:", i.e. before MyFacadeBean is bound to JNDI, which causes bean deployments to fail:

```
2010-03-25 10:47:39,068 ERROR [my.facade.FacadeFactory] (main) MyFacade not bound
2010-03-25 10:47:39,069 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[my.host.no].[/]] (main) StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at my.freemarker.servlet.FreemarkerController.setupPojoServiceFactory(FreemarkerController.java:621)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyFacade not bound
        at my.facade.FacadeFactory.getFacade(FacadeFactory.java:61)
```

After the WAR has finished its deployment, MyFacade happily (mockingly?) continues its deployment and binds the JNDI entries.

If I hot-deploy the WAR after the EAR has deployed, everything works as intended.

I even thought of depending on a dummy EJB in the EAR, and using <module-order>strict</module-order> in  jboss-app.xml to force it to load as the last module.  But alas, [JBoss 5.x does not support that](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-7106) either.  Doh!

Is there a way to depend on the JNDI entry itself?  Are there other ways of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve this on JBoss 5.1.x.

First, add a file called `aliases.txt` into the `META-INF` directory of your EAR. This file should just contain a single line with an arbitrary name / identifier for your EAR. For example, if you have my-ear.ear, your `META-INF/aliases.txt` file could contain 'my-ear'. It just needs to be something that won't clash with any other aliases declared by other apps deployed on the same server.

Next, add a `jboss-dependency.xml` file to the `META-INF` directory of your WAR, containing the following (subsituting 'my-ear' for the alias you created above):

```
<dependency xmlns="urn:jboss:dependency:1.0">
  <item whenRequired="Real" dependentState="Create">my-ear</item>
</dependency>
```

This will ensure the EAR is deployed before the WAR.

Also, if you try to deploy the WAR without the EAR being present, JBoss will log a clear deployment error message telling you about the missing dependency.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Most of our clients has moved on to AS7/EAP6 now, but this was good to know nonetheless.