# Deploy a WAR file on JBoss only if JNDI resource is available

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss, jndi

I have a multi-tier project where the application server that provides an access point to the web should deploy its WAR file *only if required remote JNDI resources are available*.

The JNDI lookup is performed on a different server within the local network, where no access from the outside world is allowed.

My problem is that right now, there is no way to tell if any of the required EJB modules are in place before starting deployment of the WAR - which will fail miserably if a JNDI lookup is not resolved (the remote services are used with Dependency Injection, so they *must* be present at startup).

Of course, I could set up a timer in my Maven build to wait for an arbitrary number of seconds between deployment of the modules, to allow the EJBs to start, but that seems like a crude hack to me, and it will not be very reliable, depending on which machine does the build.

I would be happy both if an JNDI check can be done directly on the application server, or within the Maven build, prior to deployment.
Is there something like that? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515235/can-i-make-a-war-depend-on-a-jndi-entry-in-jboss-5-1), but there never was an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this should be possible with `@Resource`, or by creating `WEB_INF/ejb-jar.xml` and using `lookup-name`.  See https://community.jboss.org/thread/213106.