# How can I know the loading process of JBoss is finished successfully?

Tags: web-applications, jboss, war

All.In my software deployment, There are many wars deployed in my JBoss, The version of it is 4.2.3.GA.

I ever thought about a solution by adding a http service in a certain war which simply return

`true/false` to indicate the whole loading get done .

But I can't be sure If this war can be loaded at the end of the loading sequence.So I hope someone can

tell me If there is any possibility to change war loading sequence in container. 
and I am also not sure I am

in the right way to fix it.

If I missed something or goes in the wrong way please kindly let me know it.

I will appreciate it . thanks.

Comment: @gebuh I had updated my post, Please review it .thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jboss deploys wars according to directory order - so if you ls your deploy directory, that's going to be the deployment order.  As far as I know the only way to change that order is to rename the artifact, there's 2 ways to do this, go by simple alphabetical order (don't forget exploded wars will get deployed first) or rename them and uncomment the PrefixDeploymentSorter attribute in conf/jboss-service.xml (I don't think this is available in version 5).
I haven't done this myself, but in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515235/can-i-make-a-war-depend-on-a-jndi-entry-in-jboss-5-1) post someone successfully used it in jboss5, maybe it can be adapted to work in jboss4 without the renaming.

Comment: Please let me make some experiment following your helpful information. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please tell me how could you find this [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515235/can-i-make-a-war-depend-on-a-jndi-entry-in-jboss-5-1)? Is it you ever review before? Or you just search in stackoverflow with some keywords?I just want to learn the searching skill from you. thanks.

Comment: I've been working with jboss for years, but never really thought about the deployment order, it was a good question.  So I did some googling for "jboss deploy order" and deployed a couple of wars to test out the results.  From [jboss.org](https://community.jboss.org/message/201628) I found the reference to PrefixDeploymentSorter and added that to my search.  [master the boss](http://www.mastertheboss.com/) is another good site for jboss info.  Also, check out the links to the right of the page, similar questions are listed.

Comment: Thanks for your nicely help. It is really valuable skill to learn.